# Sum Values within 3 tables

Tags: sql

Table 1

jh."job-hdr"

```
job-date     job-disp  job-dept  job-route  job-id  job-no
01/04/2013     6467       abc       123        22    81088
01/04/2013     6468       abc       987        36    82568
```

Table 2

rh."rec-charge"

```
charge-type    rec-id  base-sales-value
XYZ             22          700
```

Table 3

rc."rec-cost"

```
charge-type    rec-id  base-cost-value
XYZ             22          300
```

I need to be able to get the profit from this jobid of

```
700 - 300 = 400
```

This is where I have gotten up to

```
SELECT jh."job-date", jh."job-disp", jh."job-dept", jh."job-route", rc."charge-type",rh."charge-type",
SUM(rc."base-cost-value") as COSTS, 
SUM(rh."base-sales-value") as SALES,
SUM(rh."base-sales-value") - SUM(rc."base-cost-value") as PROFIT
FROM MSN.PUB."rec-chg" rh, PUB."job-hdr" jh, pub."rec-cost" rc
WHERE jh."job-date" between '2013-04-01' and '2013-04-30'
and jh."job-id" = rc."rec-id"
and rc."rec-id" = rh."rec-id"
and jh."grp-id" = '0'
and jh."job-status"<>'D'
and jh."job-no" = '81088'
and rc."charge-type" = rh."charge-type"
Group by jh."job-date", jh."job-disp", jh."job-dept", jh."job-route",rc."charge- type",rh."charge-type"
```

This is not giving me great results at all and I know I am way off. I just need to be put in the right direction.

Comment: Please tag your question with the specific RDBMS you're using, it will help avoid answers that use incompatible syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Update profit to:

```
SUM(rh."base-sales-value" - rc."base-cost-value") as PROFIT
```

And update your group by to:

```
group by jh."job-id", rc."rec-id", rh."rec-id"
```

This should give your the desired result (hopefully). Sorry didnt not have time to test it myself. The main focus is on group by, which should be applied on a field that would return multiple results for other fields you want to run the sum on.

Answer (score 0):

Your question appears is a little ambiguous, as to whether you want the results by job or by charge type.  In either case, you need to aggregate the results *before* doing the `join`.  The following query does this at the job level:

```
SELECT jh."job-date", jh."job-disp", jh."job-dept", jh."job-route", 
       COSTS, SALES, SALES - COSTS as PROFIT
FROM PUB."job-hdr" jh left outer join
     (select rh."rec-id", SUM(rh."base-sales-value") as SALES
      from MSN.PUB."rec-chg" rh
      group by rh."rec-id"
     ) rh
     on jh."job-id" = rh."rec-id" left outer join
     (select rc."rec-id", SUM(rc."base-cost-value") as COSTS
      from pub."rec-cost" rc
      group by rc."rec-id"
     ) rc
     on jh."job-id" = rc."rec-id" 
WHERE jh."grp-id" = '0' and
      jh."job-status" <> 'D' and
      jh."job-no" = '81088';
```

Notice that I replaced your implicit join syntax with explicit join syntax.  The explicit version is much better, so you should learn to use it.

Comment: This looks more like it, I had an error "non group by expression in select clause"

Comment: Can you suggest something, should i have the rc or rh in front of the COSTS and SALES?

Comment: @user3411181 . . . There should be no `group by` in the outer query at all.  That got left in from the original query, my mistake.